# Java CompletableFuture thenAcceptBothAsync vs. thenCombineAsync

Tags: java, completable-future

What's the difference between Java's CompletableFuture's methods:

```
thenAcceptBothAsync(CompletionStage<? extends U> other, BiConsumer<? super T,? super U> action)
```

and

```
thenCombineAsync(CompletionStage<? extends U> other, BiFunction<? super T,? super U,? extends V> fn)
```

other than that the former returns a `CompletableFuture<Void>` and the latter a `CompletableFuture<V>`?

Is `thenAcceptBothAsync` supposed to be used for side-effects and `thenCombineAsync` as a monadic flatMap?

I'm pretty conversant with both Scala and Twitter Futures, but the proliferation of methods on CompletableFuture is just confusing.

What I'm trying to do is to combine two asynchronous Futures, either in parallel (they both execute simultaneously) or sequentially (i.e, monadic flatMap).

Comment: If you need help implementing, it may help to give a few lines of code showing your futures and what you want to do with them in a bit more detail.
The javadoc documentation should be sufficient to understand both functions (it looks like they have no other difference than whether the function called after both futures are done is a BiConsumer or a BiFunction, no other assumption is made about how people want to use them).

Comment: For sequential execution, use [`thenCompose[Async]`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#thenCompose(java.util.function.Function)). For parallel execution both `thenCombine[Async]` and `thenAcceptBoth[Async]` are valid choices, depending on what you want to do with the results. And yes, a `BiConsumer` typically has side-effects. The documentation even mentions this: "_Unlike most other functional interfaces, `BiConsumer` is expected to operate via side-effects_".

Comment: I have no idea, how you want to combine two asynchronous futures sequentially. But the distinction between `thenAcceptBoth[Async]` and `thenCombine[Async]` is the same as between `thenAccept[Async]` and `thenApply[Async]`. Which is the same as between `acceptEither[Async]` and `applyToEither[Async​]`. Or between `runAsync` and `supplyAsync`.